# bigraph match with unordered_map

Tags: c++

for the bigraph maximum matching algorithm, I used 2 hash table(unordered_map)to solve it, but when I compiling my code, IDE told me C2100, I even don't know where my code is false, it just happened in the "xhash" document, and I think this problem is associated with iterator. Anyway, please help me to figure out this question, Thanks !

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
struct Edge
{
    int to;
    int go;
    int length;
    Edge* next;
    int ID;
};
struct Dot
{
    int data;
    Edge* first;
};
class Web
{
public:
    Web(int num);
    ~Web();
    void Insert(int i, int j, int w);
    void DFS(int s, int* visited,queue<int>&);
    void BFS(int s, int* visited);
    void show()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            Edge* p = D[i].first;
            if (p != NULL)
            {
                cout << p->length << " ";
                p = p->next;
            }
        }
    }
    void MostMatch();
private:
    int e;
    int n;
    Dot* D;
    vector<Edge*> E;
};
Web::Web(int num)
{
    e = 0;
    n = num;
    D = new Dot[num];
    for (int i = 0; i<num; i++)
    {
        D[i].first = NULL;
        D[i].data = 0;
    }
}
Web::~Web()
{
    delete[] D;
}
void Web::Insert(int i, int j, int w)
{
    Edge* p = D[i].first;
    int count = 0;
    if (D[i].first == NULL)
    {
        D[i].first = new Edge;
        D[i].first->next = NULL;
        D[i].first->length = w;
        D[i].first->to = j;
        D[i].first->go = i;
        D[i].first->ID = count++;
        E.push_back(D[i].first);
    }
    else
    {
        while (p->next != NULL)
            p = p->next;
        Edge* q = new Edge;
        p->next = q;
        q->next = NULL;
        q->length = w;
        q->go = i;
        q->to = j;
        q->ID = count++;
        E.push_back(q);
    }
    p = D[j].first;
    if (D[j].first == NULL)
    {
        D[j].first = new Edge;
        D[j].first->next = NULL;
        D[j].first->length = w;
        D[j].first->to = i;
        D[j].first->ID = count;
        e++;
    }
    else
    {
        while (p->next != NULL)
            p = p->next;
        Edge* q = new Edge;
        p->next = q;
        q->next = NULL;
        q->length = w;
        q->to = i;
        q->ID = count;
        e++;
    }
}
void Web::MostMatch()
{
    cout << "make sure it is a biggraph, press Q to quit." << endl;
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
    if (ch == 'Q')
    {}
    else
    {
        unordered_map<int, int> mape; 
        unordered_map<int, int> mapd;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            Edge* p;
            if (D[i].first)
            {
                p = D[i].first;
                if (mapd.find(i) == mapd.end())
                {
                    while (p)
                    {
                        if (mapd.find(p->to) == mapd.end())
                        {
                            mapd.insert(i,count++);
                            mapd.insert(p->to, count++);
                            mape.insert(p->ID, i);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        unordered_map<int, int>::iterator iter = mape.begin();
        while (iter != mape.end())
        {
            Edge* p = D[E[iter->first]->go].first, *q = D[E[iter->first]->to].first;
            while (p)
            {
                if (mapd.find(p->to) == mapd.end())
                {
                    while (q)
                    {
                        if (mapd.find(q->to) == mapd.end())
                        {
                            mapd.insert(p->to, count++);
                            mapd.insert(q->to, count++);
                            mape.insert(p->ID, count++);
                            mape.insert(q->ID, count++);
                            mape.erase(iter->first);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break; 
                }
            }
            iter++;
        }
        for (iter = mape.begin(); iter != mape.end(); iter++)
        {
            cout << "v" << E[iter->first]->go << " to v" << E[iter->first]->to << " ID: " << E[iter->first]->ID << endl;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    Web w1(8);
    w1.Insert(0, 3, 1);
    w1.Insert(1, 4, 1);
    w1.Insert(1, 5, 1);
    w1.Insert(2, 5, 1);
    w1.Insert(2, 6, 1);
    w1.Insert(2, 7, 1);
    w1.Insert(3, 7, 1);
    w1.MostMatch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it's about compilation error, you should paste the (complete) error message as well...

Comment: Offtopic: ['net'](https://wikidiff.com/web/net) would be the more common term (compare '*net*work' - never heard of '*web*work'; normally, should have been 'world wide net' as well, still choosing 'web' was for *aesthetic* reasons: compare 'www' to 'wwn'...).

Comment: error C2100 illegal indirection ConsoleApplication4 e:\vs\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\xhash 584 
sorry, I forgot that.

Comment: It happens in a system header, normally, the compiler should provide an entire compilation stack (xhash, line 584 -> called from someFile, line xyz -> called from yourFile, line zyx). The most interesting part is the line of your file! By the way, please learn how to write a [mcve], your code is far away from being `minimal`... (as mentioning line numbers: please don't include them in code - instead, you might mark the line producing the error via a comment in code).

Comment: its not occur in my application, but I won't suspect that something is wrong in xhash , it maybe help?:
 template<class _Iter>
  void insert(_Iter _First, _Iter _Last)
  { // insert [_First, _Last) at front, then put in place
  _DEBUG_RANGE(_First, _Last);
  for (; _First != _Last; ++_First)
   emplace(*_First);
  }

Comment: That one is for using iterators (forming a range or subrange of another container); example: `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v; mapd.insert(v.begin(), v.end());`.

Comment: Offtopic again: why do you use a `std::vector` for your edges, but a raw array for the dots? Wouldn't using a vector for both be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

> I even don't know where my code is false

This is a good reason to minimize your code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

If your compiler doesn't tell you the error message/line (and, I think, it actually does), try a different one, there is a high chance they are compatible. This one: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler tells me that lines

```
mapd.insert(i,count++);
```

and similar are wrong. Replacing them in the following way compiles:

```
mapd[i] = count++;
```

Comment: Alternatives: `std::emplace(i, count++);`, `std::insert(std::make_pair(i, count++));` - while the one you showed certainly is the most elegant...